# Android Studio: Part of Design View Hidden

Tags: android-studio

This is a new one for me.  In Design view I am unable to see the first 150 pixels of the design view window-- including the buttons/options to the left of the AppTheme button.  I've tried the Pan and Zoom tool, which seems to do nothing. It shows the full view and blueprint view filling the Pan and Zoom tool interface.  Any idea how to fix this:
[image: No way to get to the left side of the window]

Comment: Not sure that will help :)

Comment: Re-Open Project once, It Might be fixed otherwise restart Android Studio...!

Comment: Did that and even created a new project.  Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

"Window" -> "Restore Default Layout" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Just drag the mouse where your projects are to the far left of the screen and slowly move with your mouse over to the right until you will see somewhere in the middle resize pointer- thats your design view border. Click it and move to the right and it should appear! 
If you want i can try to make a gif how to do it if the above does not help.