# Android Studio Design View is cut off

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-development

When trying to view an xml using the "design" tab, the leftmost 200 pixels or so of the preview are being cut off, and I can't get Android Studio to show the full picture no matter what I do.

Here's what I'm seeing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjkEy.jpg

And a gif of the problem: https://gfycat.com/PersonalDetailedBallpython

Unfortunately the gif was too long, and cuts out some of my trying things out.
Closing the project pane does nothing, and while zoomed in, the pan and zoom detail will tell me I'm seeing the upper left corner, when in reality the leftmost 200 pixels are cut off.

Does anyone have any info that would help?  Thanks!

Comment: can you add some xml code

Comment: Are you sure there is no side scroll option? Very weird bug.

Comment: @LuísGonçalves No, there's no side scroll option :(  Even the toolbar at the top of the pane is cut off, not just the UI view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can be found here: [Android Studio: Part of Design View Hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638033/android-studio-part-of-design-view-hidden)

Pasted here: Window>Restore Default Layout